# Correct use of controllers and views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Assuming a web page, where we want to display a list of movies, register movies and edit those movies.

You could create a controller, and within the controller treat the three views (Index, Create, Edit).

Or you could create two controllers, one for treating the Index and the other to address the Create and Edit. (Since Creating and Editing Model or ViewModel share)

Or you could create three controllers, one for each view.

It can be done in three ways.
But which one is right and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers should be grouped logically around an object\functionality. If all of these three actions are related to Movies, then it should be MovieController with three actions\views.

Making new controller for each action will make your code a bit of mess.

Answer (score 2):

you'd want to create one controller for this, `MoviesController`, for example.  The operations within the controller will then make sense since the URL will look like this...

```
Movies/Create

Movies/Edit

Movies //this will just list the movies.
```

The controller could then be passed a `Movies repository` for manipulating or listing the data.

Obviously, you can create three controllers, but this would be overkill and cause maintenance headache.

Answer (score 1):

Because your business model is one , i think you have to use one controller and your required actions and views.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a controller with three actions and views (Index, Create, Edit).